# How to use Node on zsh?

Tags: node.js, bash, zsh

I am kind of new to programing world! I just installed git-bash and NodeJs on my machine; I also want to use JavaScript client-side on git-bash.
when I am on bash shell and I type node everything works perfectly and I get this message:

```
mir@Y MINGW64 /
$ node
Welcome to Node.js v16.15.1.
Type ".help" for more information.
```

but when I switch the terminal to zsh shell and I run node nothing will happen and the terminal gets frozen but will be unfrozen when I use ctrl+c:

```
mir@Y MINGW64 /
$ zsh
➜  / node
|
➜  / node
```

it will get frozen even when I change back onto bash shell:

```
mirza@Yuri MINGW64 /
$ zsh
➜  / bash

mirza@Yuri MINGW64 /
$ node
|
```

I want to be able to use node command on both versions!
any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Is there node config in .bashrc? If so you may just want to source .bashrc from .zshrc, which should pull it all in.

Comment: Don't source `.bashrc` from `.zshrc`. There's no guarantee that your `.bashrc` file is syntactically valid or semantically equivalent if execute by `zsh`. Instead, find the node configuration and add it to `.zshrc`.